# Mysql Time Zone Not Showing

Tags: mysql

I am having AN string column in my mysql database table which stores out milliseconds as a string , now I want to show Date as an ISO 8601 format like 2012-03-12T14:11:23-0400 with a Select Query as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP(response_time),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q") AS date FROM table_name;
```

But it not showing time zone , result of above  query

```
2012-10-29T14:55:47Q
```

But Actual result I want is

```
2012-10-29T14:55:47-05:00
```

Comment: Where did you get `%Q` from? I don't see it in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). There's no format code for time zone.

Comment: Taking reference from http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

Comment: This is not a working approach. If you have stored milliseconds as you've described, with a look at the data you cannot determine what timezone those milliseconds are depending on. Most MySQL functions return values according to the timezone settings of the server. And `%Q` isn't a valid output formatting parameter for `DATE_FORMAT`. Please read [this chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) in the MySQL manual how to figure out working with timezones in MySQL.

Comment: Any other way to show timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

`%Q` is not a valid date specifier in MySQL.

The timezone in MySQL can be accessed in the following ways:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone
```

If the above return `SYSTEM` it means MySQL is set to use the system's timezone and it will have to be retrieved by means other than through MySQL directly.

That said, this will only tell you what time zone the system is running currently, not anything about the dates stored as date/time values are not stored with any information about timezone.